# What is the max count of thin clients connected to ignite?

Tags: ignite

I want to create a thin client for each thread, and there may be about 100 threads on each server. If I start hundreds of servers, the Ignite cluster may have tens of thousands of thin client connections.

Can it support that many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, Ignite server can handle tens of thousands of client connections.
2. BUT **connection per thread is NOT a good idea**. Ignite client is thread-safe. You can use one client (or a small pool of clients) for any number of threads.