# Why are there so many of "Client disconnected abruptly due to network connection loss...." in the log?

Tags: java, .net, ignite, apacheignite

I started three ignite nodes, but after a while, there are a lot of the following content :

```
Line 20658: [17:07:01,115][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#33][ClientListenerProcessor] Client disconnected abruptly due to network connection loss or because the connection was left open on application shutdown. [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Connection reset]

Line 20669: [17:07:02,114][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-1-#34][ClientListenerProcessor] Client disconnected abruptly due to network connection loss or because the connection was left open on application shutdown. [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Connection reset]"
```

in the log.

**Why is this? What impact do these logs have?**

2. Occasionally, it will appear

```
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060):
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)

   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.SocketRead(Byte[] buf, Int32 pos, Int32 len)

   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.ReceiveBytes(Int32 size)

   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.ReceiveMessage()

   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.SendRequest(RequestMessage& reqMsg)

   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.DoOutInOp[T](ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction, Func`2 readFunc, Func`3 errorFunc)

   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket.DoOutInOp[T](ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction, Func`2 readFunc, Func`3 errorFunc)

   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.IgniteClient.GetOrCreateCache[TK,TV](String name)
   
at Aurora.Server.IgniteDBProxy.SaveToCache(String cacheName, String key, Object obj) in e:\Code\ProjectG_SVN\Server_Change\Code\Src\Common\DB\IgniteDBProxy.cs:line 37

   at Aurora.Server.IgniteHelper.SaveObjToIgnite(IgniteDBProxy igniteDBProxy, String key, Object obj) in e:\Code\ProjectG_SVN\Server_Change\Code\Src\Common\DB\IgniteHelper.cs:line 31

   at Aurora.Game.PlayerDBComponentSystem.SaveAllHumanDataToDB(PlayerDBComponent self) in e:\Code\ProjectG_SVN\Server_Change\Code\Src\Server\Components\PlayerDBComponent.cs:line 115

   at Aurora.Game.PlayerDBComponentSystem.Update(PlayerDBComponent self) in e:\Code\ProjectG_SVN\Server_Change\Code\Src\Server\Components\PlayerDBComponent.cs:line 51

   at Aurora.Framework.SystemCallback`1.Invoke(Entity comp) in e:\Code\ProjectG_SVN\Framework\Framework\Src\Framework\Interface\IComponent.cs:line 63

   at Aurora.Framework.EntitySystem.Update(Int32 deltaTimeMs) in e:\Code\ProjectG_SVN\Framework\Framework\Src\Framework\Entity\EntitySystem.cs:line 579,
```

why is this?

Note :

1. The thin client and ignite node are in the same network segment of the intranet.
2. ignite version: 2.14
3. thin client: .net
4. My application is multi-threaded, and I have established a thin client pool (since Ignite thin client is thread-safe, so I did this).[Ignite client is thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77252863/what-is-the-max-count-of-thin-clients-connected-to-ignite/77256233#77256233)

Comment: update question

Comment: update question again